# How to insert array key as table column and value as column value into mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have an array that looks like:

```
$frmData = array([name]=>Abhi[cell]=>050000000[email]=>abc@xyz.com[address]=>1/2 South Road)
```

Now I want to insert data into my mysql db from the array, and use the array key `[name][cell][email][address]` as table column and values as column value.

I tried several times any ways but not sure how to do it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your attempt?

Comment: "I tried several times any ways" Care to show us what you have tried?

Comment: Here, have some hints: [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
$columns = array_keys($frmData);
$values = array_values($frmData);

$query = "INSERT INTO your_table (" . implode(", ", $columns) . ") VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $values) . "')";
```

OR if you want to make make calculation on values you can loop through your array with `foreach ($frmData as $column => $value)`

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
$cols = array();
$vals = array();
foreach($frmData as $key => $val){
    $cols[]= $key;
    $vals[]= "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($val) . "'";
}
$query = 'insert into your_table(' .implode(',', $keys) . ') values (' . implode(',', $vals) . ')';
```

Comment: I was about to +1 but then i realized that this is totally injection vulnerable :P And your edit only works with strin values.